# Smooth collisions with a triangle mesh

Tags: collision-detection

I've got a ground mesh which is comprised of a collection of triangles.
[image]

When the box moves along the surface it sometimes collides with the internal edge.
[image]

The way I'm handling collisions for each triangle is first with the GJK algorithm which checks whether there is a collision or not. Then I use EPA to obtain the collision resolution normal. Followed by the Sutherland Hodgeman clipping algorithm to obtain the contact points and depth. From there, a sequential impulse solver will resolve the collision.

It's clear why this is happening, the collision normal is found by only considering each triangle in isolation and with GJK & EPA the correct minimum resolution vector can (depending on the geometry of the convex object) point in any direction.

What's not clear is how to solve this. I've really only found two online resources.

https://box2d.org/posts/2020/06/ghost-collisions/
This is great information but it only pertains to this issue in 2D. Maybe you can do something similar in 3D where you have 3 ghost vertices:

[image]

And it would seem, you'd have the information to correct/discard collision normals for edges. But things can get hairy when considering collisions around vertices since there can be an arbitrary number of triangles with that vertex forming various concave and convex surfaces. It's not clear if this idea would work in 3D. (Has anyone tried this?) Also, it apparently [doesn't work well when the edges are small compared to the convex colliding object](https://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/ghost-vertices) but maybe in practice this isn't much of a concern given reasonable edge lengths.

http://www.codercorner.com/blog/?p=1156
This paper leaves me with questions.

- It doesn't explain the purpose of the user defined contact distance. In fact, it seems to gives incorrect results. Clearly in figure 1, the green triangle is not colliding with the sphere but the algorithm can register a contact anyway.
- Apparently, the algorithm can work with other shapes besides a sphere: "We use a sphere-vs-mesh example but the same idea is applicable to other shapes." But there is no further explanation on how one would adapt the algorithm to work with a different shape.
- I question the correctness of the algorithm for concave collisions. Maybe it's designed only for convex surfaces, the paper doesn't mention this.

How can I get smooth collisions with a convex object across an arbitrary triangle mesh with concave and convex surfaces in 3D?

Comment: Are you separating your horizontal and vertical movements into separate vectors? This can help prevent false collisions on edges from the gravity vector. Adding a small extra offset to the collision resolution can also help keep your mesh floating above the other mesh.